# Initialize controller's views before loading view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry for my english, it isn't perfect.
I have an UINavigationController, whose root view controller is UITableViewController. When user taps on an accessory button of any row in the table, another view controller(DetailViewController) gets initialized, passed some data to display and pushed onto navigation controller's stack.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_detailController setRestau:_restauList[indexPath.row] atIndex:indexPath.row withCompletionBlock:^(){

    }];
    //detailController is initialized in UITableViewController's viewDidLoad method

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_detailController animated:YES];
}
```

DetailController's setRestau: method

```
@interface RFRestauDetailViewController ()
{
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *_titleLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *_ratingLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *_descriptionLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *_titleValueLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *_ratingValueLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *_descriptionValueLabel;
}
@implementation RFRestauDetailViewController

    - (void)setRestau:(RFRestaurant *)restau atIndex:(NSInteger)index withCompletionBlock:(void (^)())completionBlock
    {
        _titleLabel.text = @"Название:";
        _ratingLabel.text = @"Рейтинг:";
        _descriptionLabel.text = @"Описание:";

        _titleValueLabel.text = restau.title;
        _ratingValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", restau.rating];
        _descriptionValueLabel.text = restau.description;
    }
@end
```

DetailViewController displayed my view, but view displayed wrong data, to be precise, the view displayed itself the same way it looked like in Interface Builder. But if you click "Back" on the navigation bar, tap on an accessory button of any row in the table view, DetailViewController displays the view with correct data.
In debug mode, I've found out that each label in DetailViewController was set to nil. 
I googled a little, and understood that every view gets initialized not when its controller is initialized, but when the view is first accessed.
So I've tried to change things a little bit. I replaced with each other two statements(take a glance a the first snippet of code).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_detailController animated:YES];
    [_detailController setRestau:_restauList[indexPath.row] atIndex:indexPath.row withCompletionBlock:^(){

    }];
}
```

Please, tell me, how should I resolve this problem with view initialization.

Comment: Don't try to set the value of labels from another controller -- instead, pass the strings (or any other object you need) to the controller, and have that controller populate its own strings in its viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Nah, I'm kinda a lazy man. Plus I'm gonna need that pointer to restau in completionBlock.

Comment: You can still pass the RFRestaurant object to the RFRestauDetailViewController, but have it set all its own labels. It's better OOP practice to let each object (the controller in this case) control its own views, rather than doing it from another controller.

Answer (score 0):

That is a tricky one. 
When your details view controller is called for the first time then it was not loded. I bet that when you debug through `setRestau` that all the `IBOutlet` properties, such as `_titleLabel`, are still `nil`.

So some methods and values are send to a `nil` object, which works fine on runtime but does not do anything exept returning `0` or `nil` (if you would use a return value). 
And your values go to nirvana. 
After that your view controller's view is loaded and the `IBOutlet` get the default values from IB.

Second time you are using the same/identical view controller its view was loaded already and the values of the `IBOutlets` are set correctly.

Do the following:
Define properties in you detail view controller for all the values.
In setRestau first set these properties. 
Check if all the UIView subclasses are nil. If they are not nil, then set their values as you already do. 
In viewDidLoad check if the newly added properties are nil. When ever they are not, then use their value to set the values of their corresponding properties.

Doing so your values will appear correctly regardless whether the view controller is pushed for the first time or repeated.